# I cannot upgrade Compose from 1.1.1 to 1.2.0

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, mobile, kotlin-coroutines

Hello I am working on a new app with Compose 1.1.1 and I want to upgrade it to version 1.2.0. I am using `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0` which seems to be the problem.
This is the error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
```

And this one aswell:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Cannot find a version of 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core' that satisfies the version constraints:
```

[image]

[image]

These are the dependencies I am using:

```
dependencies {

//Hilt dependency injection
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version")
kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version")
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"

//Realm Mongo implementation
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0-native-mt'
implementation 'io.realm.kotlin:library-sync:1.0.1'
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.4.0")

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
}
```

Comment: Any reason you’re not using the latest Kotlin, version 1.7? Unlike some other languages like Java, Kotlin does not maintain backward compatibility with older versions. It is safest to try to always use the latest version, so there is less chance of a behavior change in your code if you upgrade the version later.  Also, if you try to use an old version, you will only be able to use old versions of any Kotlin-based libraries you use, as you have found with coroutines.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have mistyped my question, because actually I am using Compose so I want to upgrade to the latest version of compose. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Try adding this `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$version` instead of `core` if it is android app.

Comment: @Sylwek845 I tried this but didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the dependencies conflict. Compose **1.2.0** wants to get coroutines **1.6.1** while your Realm dependency has **1.6.0-native-mt** which is lower AND it seems like they put a strict array of versions which could be used - aka deprecated `force = true` (cannot find anything probably bc Realm is not an open-source project, but Gradle is giving a hint). I checked a changelog and according to [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-kotlin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) Realm is not compatible with the higher version and it's not planned yet.

In your case you can also force the downloaded dependency

```
 implementation ('org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0-native-mt') {
    version {
        strictly '1.6.0-native-mt'
    }
}
```

And your project most likely will be built successfully. But I'll be honest - I don't have any idea how it will impact on Compose, I would assume that it's none, but who knows? So it looks like a trade-off :)

Comment: thank you this solved my issue, but now I am getting a new error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by "SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY"`, any idea how to solve this. It seems to be something with viewmodel.

Comment: @Besart take a look at this thread https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/3484